# What is the music that plays in Bleach Episode 280 at 4:15 until 4:50?

Tags: music, bleach

I've been trying to find this soundtrack for the past 2 days and haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This song is not present in any Bleach OST, as it has never been officialy released. You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMJIk9Yas_o) as a fan remake close to the original.